# Is it valid to fit a generalized linear mixed effect model with "time" as a continuous fixed effect, but catagorical random effect?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-models, autocorrelation, glmmtmb

I would like to fit a generalized linear mixed effect model using an AR1 correlation structure in the R package `glmmTMB`. After checking [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html)

... it seems that "time" must be fitted as a factor for the random effects component i.e.

```r
glmmTMB(y ~ ar1(time_fac + 0 | group), data=dat0, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

However, I wondered if it makes sense to fit this kind of model:

```r
glmmTMB(y ~ ns(time_cont,3) + ar1(time_fac + 0 | group), 
    data=dat0, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Here I have specified the fixed effect time to be a continuous natural spline whilst retaining time as a factor for the ar1 component. The model does fit, but I am not sure if it makes sense. Also I have not really seen an explanation of WHY time must be coded as a factor for the AR1 component, and why we cannot fit a random slope?